# Cannot add margin between form elements

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a form and add some margin between form element in the class formGroup as margin 10px 0;
But it is not working and I am not sure why is that happening. I appreciate your help.
Here is the HTML

```
<div class="registrationForm">
<h2>Please fill in the form below to register</h2>
<form class="form">
<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">First Name</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">Last Name</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">Email Address</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">Password</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">Phone</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">Gender</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">Date of birth</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel"></label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

and the CSS here

```
.registrationForm
{
background-color: #FFF;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
padding: 3% 5%; 
margin-bottom: 3%;
overflow: auto;
}

.registrationForm .form
{   
margin: 10px auto;
width: 90%;
//border: 1px solid black;
overflow: auto;
}

.registrationForm .form .formGroup
{
width: 100%;
margin: 10px 0;
}

.registrationForm .form .formGroup .formLabel
{
width: 20%;
float: left;
//text-align: right;
}

.registrationForm .form .formGroup .formField
{
width: 80%;
float: left;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the floats contained within your `.formGroup` elements, currently `.formGroup` has no height so any margin applied is swallowed by the height of the children within it.

Put this on your `.formGroup` selector

```
overflow: hidden;
margin: 10px 0;
```

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/yuqvu6w4/1/

Comment: That worked perfectly fine. Thank you! Floats often confuse me, can you suggest a good guide where I can learn something more about float?

Comment: @KilvishShakal https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ see "The Great Collapse" section which explains what is happening for you here.

Answer (score 1):

You're just putting the margin-bottom in the wrong place. it should be in formField.

```css
.registrationForm
{
background-color: #FFF;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
padding: 3% 5%; 

overflow: auto;
}

.registrationForm .form
{   
margin: 10px auto;
width: 90%;
//border: 1px solid black;
overflow: auto;
}

.registrationForm .form .formGroup
{
width: 100%;
}

.registrationForm .form .formGroup .formLabel
{
width: 20%;
float: left;
//text-align: right;
}

.registrationForm .form .formGroup .formField
{
width: 80%;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="registrationForm">
<h2>Please fill in the form below to register</h2>
<form class="form">
<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">First Name</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">Last Name</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">Email Address</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">Password</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">Phone</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">Gender</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel">Date of birth</label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <label class="formLabel"></label>
    <div class="formField">
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: But in this case, we are giving margin-bottom to formField which is a text field and no margin to the label. It does work, but is it a good practice?

Comment: its as good practice as the alternative, which has the same effect

Comment: by the way you can reduce your code and make your css inherit attributes by making your registration form into an id (# not a dot)

Answer (score 0):

> you only need to add "overflow:hidden" to your class
>   ".registrationForm .form .formGroup"
>   your final code will be :

```
.registrationForm .form .formGroup {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    **overflow: hidden;**
}
```

> it will work without interrupting other code